# как получит данные с помощю php post с того что выберут

Tags: php, javascript, html

Как получить данные с `output id="rezultat"` и с `input id="a" type="number"value="1"` 
и отправить их через другую форму на этой же странице?

```
<form onsubmit="return false;"

                oninput=" 
                document.getElementById('rezultat').innerHTML 
                    = 
                parseFloat(document.getElementById('a').value)
                *
                parseFloat(document.getElementById('b').value)
                "
                    >
    <b>Sayı</b> <input id="a" type="number" style="width:40px;border: 1px solid #CCC; text-align: center;" value="1"> 
    <input id="b" type="hidden" value="<?php echo ($price-($price*$discount)/100); ?>">
                    <span style="float: right;text-align: right;font-size: 14px;font-family: tahoma;line-height: 25px;">
                        <span id="bskt_total" style="font-weight:bold;">Qiymət:<?php echo $price; ?> AZN</span><br>
                        <span id="bskt_discount" style="font-weight:bold; color:red;">Endirim:<?php echo $discount; ?>%</span><br>



                        <span id="bskt_total" style="font-weight:bold;">Cəmi:<output id="rezultat"><?php echo ($price-($price*$discount)/100); ?></output> AZN</span><br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_count" value="10" id="item_count">
                    </span>
                    <div style="float:left; width:100%; height:10px;"></div>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                        <br><br>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для отправки на другую страницу данных из формы используй его prop [action](http://php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php)
Для получения данных из инпута назначь им name определенным значением(например: send)
Тогда получить это можно будет следующим образом:

```
<?php 
  $send = $_POST['send'];
?>
```

Для проверки были отправлены данные через пост можно на кнопку отправки(c type="submit") поставить name="submit" и проверять была ли она создана:

```
<?php
  if ($_POST['send']){
     ...
  }
?>
```

Comment: но форма на этой же странице со cвоим sumbit а предыдущая форма динамична